# LiveData<String>.getValue() returns null although mPendingData holds correct value

Tags: android, data-binding, android-livedata, android-binding-adapter

I want to use a custom @BindingAdapter to set the text of a TextView using LiveData.

**TextView:**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
       app:keyToText='@{viewmodel.getText("TI_001")}'/>
```

**BindingAdapter:**

```
@BindingAdapter("keyToText")
public static void setTextViewText(TextView tv, LiveData<String> data) {
    if (data == null || data.getValue() == null) {
        tv.setText(null);
    } else {
        tv.setText(data.getValue());
    }
}
```

Using the debugger, I already checked that the data object holds the correct value, which it does:

[image]

But unfortunately data.getValue() always returns null, so the text isn't set to the provided TextView.

Am I missing something? I really need this to work this way... hopefully.

**UPDATE**

The lifecycleowner is set to the binding as followed:

```
mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

When I use

```
viewModel.getText("TI_001").observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            tv.setText(s);
        }
    });
```

I can read the value of observed LiveData without any problems.

**UPDATE 2**

Viewmodels getText method:

```
public LiveData<String> getText(String key){
    return textRepository.getText(key);
}
```

textRepository's getText method:

```
public LiveData<String> getText(String id){
    return textDao.findById(id);
}
```

And textDao's findById method:

```
@Query("SELECT text.text FROM text WHERE text.id LIKE :id")
LiveData<String> findById(String id);
```

Comment: Is this LiveData ever active? is the lifecycle owner set on the binding?

Comment: Yes, the lifecycleowner is set and when I use viewmodel.getText("TI_001").observe(this, new Observer( etc )); in my lifecycleowner, I can read the value as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found a solution for my problem:

```
@BindingAdapter("keyToText")
public static void setTextViewText(TextView tv, LiveData<String> data) {
    if (data == null) {
        tv.setText(null);
    } else {
        data.observeForever(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                tv.setText(data.getValue());
                data.removeObserver(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So I'm basically observing my LiveData only for the first onChanged event and removing the used observer right after setting the text.